# Typo3 8.7.16: Setting the options.defaultUploadFolder at Page TSConfig not working

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-8.x

I'm trying to set the **options.defaultUploadFolder** at Page TSConfig, but it's not working. I have different websites in one typo and the default upload folder should be set for each website. Setting the defaultUploadFolder at User TSConfig is working, but that is not a solution for me, because I have also usergroups with access for all websites.

```
#working only at User TSConfig
options.defaultUploadFolder=1:/websiteA/uploads/
```

I thought that it's possible after reading this https://forge.typo3.org/issues/68895

Comment: nobody any idea? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one of the latest comments in this issue on TYPO3 forge (https://forge.typo3.org/issues/68895#note-11) and commit message (https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/repository/revisions/f54e28559d059495f46f3565bdfa06e68e518d85) there was added only a hook, which you can use to set default upload folder.

There is an extension which uses this hook and allows to change default upload folder using PageTSconfig - https://github.com/beechit/default_upload_folder/
It allows to set the different default upload folders for each TCA table and column. 
If that is not enough for you, it is easy to use this hook and do whatever you need:
https://github.com/beechit/default_upload_folder/blob/1.0.0/ext_localconf.php#L4-L5
https://github.com/beechit/default_upload_folder/blob/1.0.0/Classes/Hooks/DefaultUploadFolder.php

Comment: Thank you, I'm already using this extension. I modified it a little bit to set the default folder for a page (https://pastebin.com/Sn26W9D6)

Comment: Modifikation/Classes/Hooks/DefaultUploadFolder.php